Integral derived from the correction factor of Sterling's approximation leading to a Puiseux series of polygammas
Sterling's approximation tells us that
$$x!\approx\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x}$$
Taken and expanded upon from Spiegel, 1964, $\forall x>0\;\exists 0<\theta<1:$
$$\Gamma(x+1)=\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x} e^{\frac{\theta}{12x}}$$
This gives $\theta=12x(\ln\Gamma(x+1)+x-x\ln(x)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi x))$, which starts with a removeable discontinuity at $(0,0)$ and asymptotically approaches $1$ in a similar manner to $\tanh(x)$ and $\operatorname{erf}(x)$. Since $1-\theta$ is a bounded function rapidly approaching $0$, I now want the area.
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}1-\theta dx=\lim\limits_{(\epsilon,N)\to(0^{+},\infty)}\int\limits_{\epsilon}^{N}1-12x\ln\Gamma(x+1)-12x^{2}+12x^{2}\ln(x)+6x\ln(2\pi x)dx\\
=\lim\limits_{(\epsilon,N)\to(0^{+},\infty)}\int\limits_{\epsilon}^{N}1-12x\ln\Gamma(x)-12x\ln(x)-12x^{2}+12x^{2}\ln(x)+6x\ln(2\pi)+6x\ln(x)dx\\
=\lim\limits_{(\epsilon,N)\to(0^{+},\infty)}\int\limits_{\epsilon}^{N}1-12x^{2}+6\ln(2\pi)x+(12x^{2}-6x)\ln(x)-12x\ln\Gamma(x)dx\\
=\lim\limits_{(\epsilon,N)\to(0^{+},\infty)}\left[x-4x^{3}+3\ln(2\pi)x^{2}+(4x^{3}-3x^{2})\ln(x)\right]_{\epsilon}^{N}-\int\limits_{\epsilon}^{N}4x^{2}-3x+12x\ln\Gamma(x)dx\\
=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}(4\ln(N)-\frac{16}{3})N^{3}+(3\ln(2\pi)+\frac{3}{2}-3\ln(N))N^{2}+N-\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int\limits_{\epsilon}^{N}12x\psi_{-1}(x)dx\\
=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}(4\ln(N)-\frac{16}{3})N^{3}+(3\ln(2\pi)+\frac{3}{2}-3\ln(N))N^{2}+N-12N\psi_{-2}(N)+12\psi_{-3}(N)+\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}12\epsilon\psi_{-2}(\epsilon)-12\psi_{-3}(\epsilon)$$
Apparently $\psi_{-2}(0)=\psi_{-3}(0)=0$, so only the terms in $N$ remain. I put $12\psi_{-3}(N)-12N\psi_{-2}(N)$ into WolframAlpha, and the generalised Puiseux series expansion at $N=\infty$ was precisely
$$(\frac{16}{3}-4\ln(N))N^{3}+(3\ln(N)-\frac{3}{2}-3\ln(2\pi))N^{2}-N+\frac{3\zeta(3)}{2\pi^{2}}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{N})$$
This means everything in $N$ immediately disappears, giving
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}1-\theta dx=\frac{3\zeta(3)}{2\pi^{2}}$$
My first question is if this looks right to you. Given the specific usage of $e^{\frac{1}{12}}$ I was half-expecting the Glaisher-Kinkelin Constant $A=e^{\frac{1}{12}-\zeta'(-1)}$ to appear. My second question is how you would get that series expansion. I could guess it would be something like that, up to a constant, as the infinite terms all had to cancel due to the integral converging, but I've barely seen Puiseux series before so I'd have no way to organically get the constant. My third question is if there's a more elegant method to get this value, as this was very brute force and required WolframAlpha.

You do not need to work with $\epsilon$

You are correct. Repeating your calculations
$$I=\int (1-\theta)\,dx=x-\frac 32 x^2-\frac {16} 3 x^3+4x^3\log(x)+3 x^2 \log (2 \pi  x)+$$ $$12 \psi ^{(-3)}(x+1)-12 x \psi
   ^{(-2)}(x+1)$$
$$J=\int_0^N (1-\theta)\,dx=-3 (4 \log (\color{red}{\large A})-4 \psi ^{(-3)}(N+1)+4 N
   \psi ^{(-2)}(N+1)+\log (2 \pi ))-$$ $$4 N^3+\frac{4}{3} N^3 (3 \log
   (N)-1)+\frac{3}{2} N^2 (2 \log (\pi N)-1+\log (4))+N$$ Expanding as series for large $N$,
$$J=\frac{3 \zeta (3)}{2 \pi ^2}-\frac{1}{30 N}+\frac{1}{315 N^3}-\frac{1}{700
   N^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^7}\right)$$ which gives tight upper and lower bounds.
Glaisher-Kinkelin constant disappears by the series expansion of $\psi ^{(-2)}(N+1)$ and $\psi ^{(-3)}(N+1)$ terms.
